.Xdefaults: How to Target Firefox Only
Trying to modify the .Xdefaults maximumMaximumSize and limitResize properties only for Firefox applications. Is there a way to target Firefox applications when writing to Xdefaults while not affecting other xterm windows? Any assistance is much appreciated!
Found this post, but when I tried doing Firefox*limitResize:true in my .Xdefaults and relaunched the application that uses Firefox, it did not take effect
